Database connection fails unless I manually connect to database first
I'm developing an application in Python that will interact with a MySQL database. I'm working with a local copy of the database, using MySQL Server 8.0.40, and I'm running into an issue where the database connection will fail in the app until I manually connect to the database, either through the MySQL CLI or MySQL Workbench.
This is only necessary once each reboot, which leads me to believe it's an issue with MySQL Server service in Windows (10 Enterprise). This also suggests that it wont be an issue in production, since the database will be hosted on a server, but I want to ensure that a manual connection to the database was not necessary every time the server restarted.
Here's a snippet from my code (with limited, but obviously necessary, obfuscation):
try:
    # create database engine using the database connection string
    self.engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/database")

    # validation database connection by running a query
    with self.engine.begin() as conn:
        self.test_query()

except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Unable to connect to the remote database.")

The error that I get is: pandas AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'.
Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!

The Dealing with Disconnects docs might be relevant.  Have you tried create_engine(url, pool_pre_ping=True)?
